# OpenLayers 3 - display layer WFS in EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I have to display a layer from a WFS service (http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Bacini_idrografici.map) using OpenLayers 3.x API (..there's a reason). The WFS service is exposed in [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=EPSG:4326&r=10).

In similar cases I have always used the following code successfully:

```
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Bacini_idrografici.map', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'ID.ACQUEFISICHE.BACINIIDROGRAFICI.PRINCIPALI',
                srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326'
            }
        }).done(loadFeatures)
        .fail(function () {
        alert("error loading vector layer");
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
});

function loadFeatures(response) {
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
  sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
}

var vectorLayerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceWFS,
});
```

But now, this layer WFS isn't displayed on the map and I do not understand why?

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your view projection also EPSG:4326?

Comment: Yes of course,  in ol.view  I set : projection: 'EPSG:4326'

Comment: check your axis orders match

Comment: axis orders are right too

Answer (score 2):

I presume your view is in a diferent projection because your code works when the view is in EPSG:4326.  When the view projection differs from the WFS you will need to transform the bbox extent for the WFS request from view projection to EPSG:4326, then transform the features from EPSG:4326 to view projection when reading them.

```
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
        var extent4326 = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        var extent4326x = [extent4326[1], extent4326[0], extent4326[3], extent4326[2]];
        $.ajax('http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Bacini_idrografici.map', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'ID.ACQUEFISICHE.BACINIIDROGRAFICI.PRINCIPALI',
                srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
                bbox: extent4326x.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326'
            }
        }).done(loadFeatures)
        .fail(function () {
        alert("error loading vector layer");
        });
        function loadFeatures(response) {
            var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response, {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: projection
            }));
        }
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
});

var vectorLayerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceWFS,
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately the problem remains: layer WFS is'nt displayed !!

Comment: There was misplaced bracket, now corrected.  There's no reason why you can't use a different view projection such as EPSG:3857 regardless of the vector data projection.  I didn't use your exact code, to simplify the test I used fetch instead of your jquery ajax http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/wfs-italy.html  The source only produces data when the bbox includes the whole of Italy, so if you want to open at a higher zoom it would be better to use the default loading strategy (all) http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/wfs-italy-all.html

Comment: Here are working links using jquery ajax http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/wfs-italy-ajax.html  http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/wfs-italy-all-ajax.html

Comment: Awesome ... now it's work fine.
I think your working example will be very useful, because many WFS layer are exposed in EPSG 4326.
Many thanks !!

Comment: I've realised the bbox loading strategy problem was due to the axis order, it is a standard WFS after all.  I've updated the links and answer.  However it is still probably more efficient to load all in cases such as this with a relatively small amount of data covering a single country.