# WFS how to consume with different coordinate system?

Tags: openlayers, proj, epsg

I have a WFS in EPSG:4167. My map view has EPSG:3857. How to make the WFS work on a map view with different coordinates?

I used this to define my coordinate system from wfs:

```
import { register } from 'ol/proj/proj4.js';
proj4.defs("EPSG:4167", "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs");

register(proj4);
```

Note it is a third party wfs, so I only can use this EPSG.

Any ideas?

My first thought is that I should get the geojson from WFS and then transform the entire geojson using proj4 lib and display it on map (I'm using openlayers). Not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Similar to this question.  Replace 'EPSG:4326' with 'EPSG:4167', change any other parameters to suit your service (and you probably won't need to use YX axes) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308399/openlayers-3-display-layer-wfs-in-epsg4326